# Migration from Moss 2007 to Office 365 2013 cloud

Tags: sharepoint-online

External SharePoint Environment (MOSS External) installation is beginning to reach an unsupported situation and running on WS 2003, SQL 2005 and SharePoint 2007.Further the service depends on a legacy AD solution.

Currently we have the MOSS External environment in Production running on SharePoint 2007. Wanted position would be to have it upgraded to SharePoint 2013 in Office 365. However prefers to have the full solution migrated to Office 365.

Could you please help on this how to migrate the sharepoint 2007 to office 365 2013 cloud what prerequisities i need to this?

Comment: You can't migrate a SharePoint 2007 directly to O365, my apologies.
You have to migrate your farm to SharePoint 2010, then to SharePoint 2013 and then to O365.

Once this is done, you can export your site using "Export-SPWeb" with PowerShell

Answer (score 2):

To be very clear: You can't migrate a server solution to Office 365/SharePoint Online unless you have taken these step in development the first time. And you have a 2007 solution which means it's highly unlikely that it’s the case.

The suggestion is to develop the things you really need and deploy it for the cloud. Your content should be migrated using a third party tool or a migration tool developed by yourself or your vendor. I think the fastest and most cost effective way is to buy/subscribe to an existing tool. But the choice is yours.

Answer (score 1):

You have use 3rd party tools to migrate from 2007 to office 365, their is no ootb method available for this.

3rd party tools will migrate content, metadata,permission n some extent of customization.

But if you have full trusted code (solutions), this will not migrate and msft don't allow full trust code in 365. You have to rewrite the code in app model. That is what new way of development.

You check sharegate,metalogix and others